# Crash in UIApplication.isIdleTimerDisabled

Tags: ios, uiapplication, idle-timer

I have a published app that has a need to keep the display on for an extended period of time.  I use `UIApplication.isIdleTimerDisabled` to control it, setting it true when I need to keep the display on, and setting it false when it's no longer needed.

Since the app is distributed through the Apple App Store, I get reports when crashes occur.  I sometimes get a report that points to a crash at a line where I call `UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false`, i.e., where I'm restoring the normal state of affairs after the screen has been on for a while.  Below is a screen shot  of the stack trace.

[image]

I'm unable to reproduce the problem on my own.  There are thousands of users who have downloaded and tried the program, and I only get one or two crash reports a week, so the problem must arise from some infrequently-occuring set of conditions.  The crash reports come from a variety of iPhones and iPads running iOS 13 and 14.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason message that comes with the crash?  My suspicion is that you need to dispatch to the main thread because controlling the display is UI-related.  But since it's not easily reproduced, I'm not *sure* of that answer.

Comment: You may be right.  I'm going to out the call in the main thread and see if it goes away.

Comment: That NSException is probably spitting some helpful message in the app's console log. Do you get those with crash reports?